# What do I need to use to make those two charts in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, mobile, frontend

[charts made in figma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcQC8.jpg)

I was asked to do them and I've never done a chart before

I searched for some libs but I don't know which one to choose

Comment: Chart.js (https://www.chartjs.org/) is one option, but it all depends on which source you use for data and how detailed it is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I like Taiga UI's charts. https://taiga-ui.dev/charts/bar-chart

Answer (score 0):

First off you can use tailwind css for that. or use regular old css. good luck!